# Question of about natural number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the smallest natural number that is double the square of a natural number and five times the fifth power of a natural number.

Comment: Have you tried something? Surely, the divisors must include some $2$'s and $5$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're looking for an answer of the form $N=2^x\cdot5^y\cdot z$.  Clearly, the smallest solution would have $z=1$.

We are told that $2^{x-1}\cdot5^y$ is a perfect square, so $x-1$ and $y$ are both even.  Also, $2^x\cdot5^{y-1}$ is a perfect fifth power, so $x$ and $y-1$ are both multiples of five.

Rearranging that, $x$ is odd and a multiple of five, and $y$ is even and one more that a multiple of five.  The smallest possible natural solutions to that are $x=5,y=6$, so $$N=2^5\cdot5^6=500000$$.